# MapConfig in Hazelcast Jet

Tags: hazelcast

I was using below configuration in Hazelcast IMDG.

Now I want to use same configuration with jet also.

```
    @Bean
    public static Config config() {
        System.err.println("config class");
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("hazelcast");
        MapConfig mapCfg = new MapConfig();
        mapCfg.setName("t1");
        mapCfg.setBackupCount(2);
        mapCfg.setTimeToLiveSeconds(300);
        MapStoreConfig mapStoreCfg = new MapStoreConfig();
        mapStoreCfg.setClassName(PersonMapStore.class.getName()).setEnabled(true);
        mapCfg.setMapStoreConfig(mapStoreCfg);
        config.addMapConfig(mapCfg);
        return config;

    }
```

How to set MapConfig for hazelcast jet.

```
    JetInstance jet = Jet.newJetInstance(null);

    IMap<String, Person> map2 = jet .getMap("t1");
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Jet.newJetInstance(JetConfig)` takes `JetConfig` object, which has `setHazelcastConfig` method to set config for IMDG:

```
@Bean
public static Config config() {
    ...
}

@Bean
public static JetConfig jetConfig() {
    JetConfig jetConfig = new JetConfig();
    jetConfig.setHazelcastConfig(config());
    ...
    return jetConfig;
}
```